# Resolving Template Variable in Resource Interface for Jersey Proxy Client

Tags: java, jersey-2.0, jersey-client

I have an issue resolving a class-level @Path annotation on a interface as such. I'm passing this interface to a WebResourceFactory in Jersey proxy client but it's immediately failing with an IllegalStateException.

The interface definition:

```
@Path("{entity}")
public interface EntityResource {
    @GET
    @Produces("*/xml")
    Entity get(@PathParam("view") EntityType view);
}
```

The exception I get:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: The template variable 'entity' has no value
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.getUri(JerseyWebTarget.java:135)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:215)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyWebTarget.request(JerseyWebTarget.java:60)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.proxy.WebResourceFactory.invoke(WebResourceFactory.java:322)
```

Any suggestions on how to resolve the "entity" template variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing some investigation in the jersey-proxy-client source code, I found that all template variables are resolved with annotations on the method declaration. There was an issue in how Apache CXF generated my interfaces. I have a mismatch between the @PathParam and the @Path. @Path uses "entity" and my @PathParam uses "view". They both need to be the same in order for the template variable to resolve correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar problem and I was able to resolve it without matching `@Path` and `@PathParam` values. I used `@RequestTemplate` which actually does transformation from `entity` into `view`:

```
@APIGatewayIntegration(
      requestTemplates =
          @RequestTemplate(
              mimeType = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,
              template = "{\"entity\": \"$input.params('view')\"}"),
      type = "aws",
      contentHandling = "CONVERT_TO_TEXT",
      httpMethod = HTTP_POST_METHOD,
      passthroughBehavior = "WHEN_NO_TEMPLATES"
)
```

I use my interface in AWS API GW. Hope this will be useful.